# Using Arduino to do very basic image processing

Tags: arduino

I'm looking at implementing an algorithm I wrote for Android on an Arduino. The algorithm is already pretty basic, but I have a lot of ways to optimize it still. It boils down to detection of blobs and a single channel of color would work fine. The most important part would be thresholding and detecting blobs (which I haven't figured to how to do with the limited resources, but that aside).

Doing the math, most instructions on Atmel chips use only one clockcycle. For an image of 320*240 at 30 fps, I come to the minimum of 2304000 clockcycles if one pixel requires one cycle. Given an 8mhz CPU, I would at max be allowed 3.5 clockcycles and double that for 16mhz. (I could skip parts of frames if previously there were no blobs found in the vicinity).

That seems doable, but I'm guessing there's more at play than this. Input seems the most troubling to me; an analog signal from a camera needs an adc (which is limited to max 10000 on most Arduinos), but could I use a comparator instead and do the thresholding analog? If so, is there documentation on this? Also, would it help if I received significant bits by interrupt or would that take an equal amount of clockcycles?
Alternatively I could use a serial camera, but I'd imagine this would require more clockcycles. Also I wouldn't be able to do thresholding with a comparator.

Can someone verify/comment on my thoughts on this? What methods are readable?

Comment: 7 instructions are very very very VERY few. For instance, if you just write `mymatrix[row][col]++;` there are 1) get row from memory and put it in a register. 2) get col from memory and put it in a register. 3) multiply row by the number of columns. 4) add row (multiplied) and column 5) add the result to mymatrix 6) get the content from the memory cell you just obtained and sum it (the assembly instruction is just one to fetch and increment). 7) write the content to the memory cell. Now I'm not really sure about all the steps, but they should be pretty close to the actual code.

Comment: Now, if we assume that the matrix has a total number of elements less than 256 (so for instance 64*8 matrix), these are 7 assembly instructions. Instr. 1, 2, 3, 6 and 7 require 2 clock cycles, while 4 and 5 just 1. This means 12 clock cycles just to increment one value in the matrix. And I haven't considered that you should also store the number of columns in a register.. Anyway if the number of instructions increases a lot if instead of 8 bit registers you use 16 bit ones. So in my opinion no, it does not seem doable for me. Just take a faster uC (ST has cheap - <10$ - boards) or better a DSP

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the reply. I just came across the STM32 (Cortex M3) which seems popular and cheap, would that suffice? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Well, I'm not very expert in this field. I just know that I bought a Nucleo F446RE which costs less than an arduino (less than 10€) and is much faster. The only "problem" is that it is not "arduino code compatible" (you won't have the arduino common functions like DigitalWrite). That said, I don't know if it would suffice. If you manage to write very simplified code maybe you can.. The analog frontend is the real problem here, but maybe using a comparator you can solve this.. Otherwise use an (external) flash ADC, or better a digital camera (with for instance an SPI interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STM32 seems more feasible for image processing. For now, I'll stick to Android as programming the STM32 seems pretty time consuming.